Quasi-equivalent vs. homotopy equivalent functors in $A_\infty$ categories
Suppose that $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}$ are strictly unital $A_\infty$ categories, and $\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G}: \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ are (strictly unital) functors.
On one hand, we can say that $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are quasi-equivalent if the honest functors $H(\mathcal{F}), H(\mathcal{G}): H(\mathcal{A}) \rightarrow H(\mathcal{B})$ agree. (Perhaps, morally, I want to write 'up to natural isomorphism' here.)
On the other, I can consider $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ as objects of the functor category $\sf{fun}(\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B})$. Here, I say that $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are homotopy equivalent if they are isomorphic as elements of $H(\sf{fun}(\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}))$; to spell this out, this is if there are natural transformations $S: \mathcal{F} \Rightarrow \mathcal{G}$ and $T: \mathcal{G} \Rightarrow \mathcal{F}$, a pre-natural transformation $P: \mathcal{F} \Rightarrow \mathcal{F}$  with $$\mu^1_{\sf{fun}(\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B})}(P) = T \circ S - \mathrm{Id}_F,$$
and similar for $S \circ T$, via a pre-natural transformation $Q$.
Is it true that if $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are quasi-equivalent then they are homotopy equivalent?
If the answer is 'not in general', are there conditions upon $\mathcal{B}$ which make it so? I think, if I understand the literature, that if $\mathcal{B}$ is the (dg) category of chain complexes so that the functor category is $\sf{Mod}_{\mathcal{A}^{\mathrm{opp}}}$ then the answer is 'yes' - perhaps provided that the ground ring is a field of characteristic two?
(This is, clearly, a somewhat naiive question to ask; I ask it because of the general phenomenon in $A_{\infty}$ categories that often quasi-somethings are also homotopy-somethings, usually via some sort of perturbation theory argument - I can't see anything to the effect of the above in, e.g. Seidel's book, but I also lose my marbles a little moving between the relevant categories and so could quite easily have overlooked something.)

As you expect, the answer is negative in general, although counterexamples are relatively recent. You can find a counterexample in:
Alberto Canonaco y Paolo Stellari, «Non-Uniqueness of Fourier–Mukai Kernels», Mathematische Zeitschrift 272, n.º 1 (1 de octubre de 2012): 577-88, https://doi.org/10.1007/s00209-011-0950-3.
There, it's stated in terms of Fourier-Mukai functors between derived categories of elliptic curves. However, it's equivalent to your question. This is explained in:
Francesco Genovese, «The Uniqueness Problem of Dg-Lifts and Fourier-Mukai Kernels», Journal of the London Mathematical Society 94, n.º 2 (2016): 617-38, https://doi.org/10.1112/jlms/jdw052.
There, you also find sufficient conditions to get a positive answer to your question.

Take a formal diffeomorphism of $n$-dimensional affine space, meaning a change of variables given by formal power series $(f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n),\dots,f_n(x_1,\dots,x_n))$ preserving the origin. This preserves the structure sheaf at the origin (the one-dimensional simple module over the power series ring); hence it induces an $A_\infty$-automorphism of the $Ext$ algebra of that sheaf, which is an exterior algebra.
Here, you can see the discrepancy very clearly: the action on $H^*(A)$ only gives the Jacobian of the diffeomorphism, whereas the $A_\infty$-automorphism structure recovers the higher order terms.
